# Why α symbol turns into <U+03B1> after flextable and officer update?

Tags: r, flextable, officer

As in the title: before the update exported .docx file contained α symbol - after the update exported .docx file displays <U+03B1>. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`U+03B1` is [the unicode](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+03B1) for the character `α`, which you mentioned.

If you are using the `α` symbol directly in officer you might need to instead supply the unicode directly with `\U03B1`.

```r
# Using the symbol directly
cat("α")
> a 

# Using the supplied unicode
cat("\U03B1")
> α
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>